# Adding lists together with a loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I'm trying to add lists together using a loop. Here is some example data.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), var2= 1:11)
> df
   var1 var2
1     1    1
2     1    2
3     2    3
4     2    4
5     2    5
6     2    6
7     3    7
8     3    8
9     3    9
10    3   10
11    3   11
```

I've run this loop code, and would like the items to be stored in a file that contains 3 lists

```
list_container <- list()
for (i in  unique(df$var1) ) {
  templist <-  df[ df$var1==i , "var2"] 
  list_container <- list(list_container, templist)
}
```

it doesn't work, and ends up looking like this

```
> list_container
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
list()

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

I want the 3 sets of list to sit separately, it should end up like this

```
list_result <- list(1:2, 3:6, 7:11)
> list_result
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

Is there anyway I can modify my code to get the desired result? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` would be more direct and faster

```
with(df, unname(split(var2, var1)))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

---

If we want to use the `==` with `unique` elements, initialize with a NULL `list` of `length` same as the `length` of `unique` elements of 'var1' column.  Loop over the sequence of unique elements, and assign the subset of 'var2' to the `i`th element of 'list_container'

```
un1 <- unique(df$var1)
list_container <- vector('list', length(un1))
for(i in seq_along(un1)) 
    list_container[[i]] <- df$var2[df$var1 == un1[i]]
```

-output

```
list_container
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: There seems a lot of ways to do this, and all great answers. btw, thanks for the second code, it's very versatile for my purposes, and for explaining what it's doing. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `unstack`:

```
unstack(df, var2~var1)
$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 3 4 5 6

$`3`
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

if you do not want the names, you can get rid of them:

```
unname(unstack(df, var2~var1))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `tapply`

```
> with(df, tapply(var2, var1, c))
$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 3 4 5 6

$`3`
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

or `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(var2 ~ ., df, c)$var2
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11
```